# cant render links for d3 radial tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a complete newbie to D3.

I'm trying to generate a D3 radial tree. So, each node has properties x0 and y0 which indicate its co-ordinates on the canvas.

I used the following code to generate the links :

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function (d) {
            debugger;
            return [d.y0, d.x0];
        });
```

I use it in the following manner :

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(links)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", diagonal);
```

However, I get the following error type :

> Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M0,0C, , -145.62305898749054,105.80134541264516"
>     attrFunction
>     (anonymous function)
>     d3_selection_each 
>     d3_selectionPrototype.each
>     d3_selectionPrototype.attr
>     (anonymous function)
>     (anonymous function)
>     event 
>     respond

All my tree nodes have x0 and y0 properties (None of the nodes have them undefined).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple issues:

1) svg.selectAll(".link") should be d3.selectAll. Maybe you have svg = d3.select("svg") though

2) Should you be returning d.x and d.y instead of d.x0 and d.y0 according to https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#diagonal

> ## diagonal.projection([projection])
>
> If projection is specified, sets the projection to the specified
>   function. If projection is not specified, returns the current
>   projection. The projection converts a point (such as that returned by
>   the source and target accessors) of the form {x, y} to a two-element
>   array of numbers. The default accessor assumes that the input point is
>   an object with x and y attributes:
>
> `function projection(d) {   return [d.x, d.y]; }`

I tried to modify your code:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
        return [d.y, d.x];
    });

var link = d3.select("svg")//added
    .append("g")//added
    .selectAll("path")//modified
    .data(links)
    .enter().insert("path", "g")//modified
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", diagonal);
```

Here is some sample code that may be helpful:

```
nestedData = d3.nest()
  .key(function (el) { return el.user })
  .entries(incData);

packableData = { id: "root", values: nestedData }

var depthScale = d3.scale.category10([0, 1, 2]);

var treeChart = d3.layout.tree();
treeChart.size([500, 500])
    .children(function (d) { return d.values });

var linkGenerator = d3.svg.diagonal();

d3.select("svg")
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "treeG")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(treeChart(packableData))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
    });

//circle representing each node that we color with same scale used for circle pack
d3.selectAll("g.node")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function (d) { return depthScale(d.depth) })
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .style("stroke-width", "2px");

d3.selectAll("g.node")
    .append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return d.id || d.key || d.content })

d3.select("#treeG").selectAll("path")
    .data(treeChart.links(treeChart(packableData)))
    .enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("d", linkGenerator)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", "2px");
```